# Git override last commit

Tags: git

I have a commit which has some minor bugs. I don't want to send the bugfix in a new commit, because I will send a pull request, so I want the changes to be as straightforward as possible. So I'd like to remove the old commit, but keep it's changes and send a new one after I applied my bug fixes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, there are two methods. First is simple, just use:

```
git commit --amend
```

The second is a little complex, but more flexible. You no need to delete you old commit. You can just make new commit with your bug fixes above your old commit. So, the history will be look like this:

```
Old commit ---> New commit
```

Now you can execute:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

You will see something like this:

```
pick hash new commit
pick hash old commit with bugs

# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

Just write `squash` instead of `pick` for the old commit and save changes. After this you will edit commit message for squashed commits and both commits will be squashed into one. More about this, you will find - [7.6 Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: How to "save the changes" by rebase?

Comment: I already found out `esc -> :wq -> enter` on windows with git bash, so I assume it uses the default cli text editor. I got an error message about `error: could not apply 878798b...` and I got merge conflicts by the files again.

Comment: I'll backup the files and fork again. It is simpler this way. These solutions did not work by me. Actually I already tried amend a few months ago in a similar situation and I run into the same merging problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Amend* is what you're looking for. It simply adds changes to previous commit.

```
git commit --amend
```

Comment: I tried out amend, now I have 3 commits instead of one and I had to resolve merge conflicts. So it definitely did not work.

Comment: Well, amend definitely works, I just wonder how did you manage to make three commits out of that:)

Comment: Well by me it did not work. I used webstorm git commit checked the amend checkbox. After that I got a merge conflict screen with the remote/origin, since the latest commit was already pushed.